# React.useEffect runs 4 times instead of once

Tags: react-hooks, use-effect

I am using a "service" to get 4 data items on load. 3 arrays and 1 object
So I use the following:

```
const { datacol, loaddata, dpcServices ,dpcServicesDetails ,meDetails} = EcgInitialDataSPService();

React.useEffect(() => {
loaddata();
}, []);
```

I notice, in the debugger, that "loaddata();" runs 4 times instead of once.
React.useEffect should run only once. do I need to add something in the line

```
 }, []);
```

? I tried :

```
}, [],[],[],null);
```

But tslint shows it as an error

Comment: The implementation of the `useEffect` is correct. `loaddata()` should run once. Is the element mounting and unmounting 4 times?

Comment: My guess is that `loaddata()` changes one of the props, which causes the whole component to re-render

Comment: Any idea of how I can tell what causes the re-render?  where do I put console.log(???)